# I created a new content element: how do I print it out?

Tags: 7

I created a new content element for the page content type.
How would I print out the content of that text area in page.tpl.php?

Comment: Hello Jordash; welcome on _Drupal Answers_. What do you mean with "I created a new content element"?

Answer (score 1):

Your question hints that you're not quite yet understanding some of the basics of the Drupal CMS. I'd recommend you do a little reading about nodes, content types and paths.

The page.tpl.php template is the master page template for your entire theme. That means every page output regardless of node type or non-node page altogether.

Your node.tpl.php template is the template for specific nodes. You can create node-MYTPE.tpl.php to control a specific node type.

For further details, see [Theming Drupal 6 and 7](http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7), and [Drupal 6 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089642).

Comment: It is not necessary to change a template file, if the OP is referring to a field created through the Drupal 7 field API. It is important to understand what the OP meant with "content element," though.

Comment: I know about that but it doesn't really suit what I needed..

Comment: by content element I meant I have the regular page content and then another piece of content (called Sidebar), since every page on the site is going to have these two types of content it isn't necessary to create seperate node types, I'm confused on the syntax for Drupal 7 of printing out the new content field I created.

Comment: @Jordash You should make your question clearer.

Comment: Yeah sorry i'm not familiar with all the terms, no one has really answered my question yet....

Comment: I'd say the sidebar content should be a block. If you need to get fancy with the rules for placement try the Context module.

Comment: How do I make the Sidebar Content a Block I need to give people the ability to add HTML to it based on the page that they created so a Block isn't really the right option i'd think.

Comment: Ahhh, perhaps CCK Block is your ticket. You can route node fields into a block within a sidebar region. Super useful module.